# Calling instance method in class method with Singleton

Tags: ios, singleton, instance, class-method

I have read about calling instance method in class method is the best way with Singleton.

I have tried it but it didn't work. I am trying to call the void method in `@selector()` but I couldn't. Please where would be my issue?

.H

```
+ (void)normalizeCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withLables:(NSArray *)lbls sx:(CGFloat)sx widths:(NSArray *)widths;
- (void)edit;
```

.M

```
+ (void)normalizeCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withLables:(NSArray *)lbls sx:(CGFloat)sx widths:(NSArray *)widths
{

    static PozisyonOzetiTableCell *sharedMyManager = nil;
static BOOL initialized = NO;

if(!initialized)
{
    initialized = YES;
    sharedMyManager = [[PozisyonOzetiTableCell alloc] init];
}
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

//// I have tried edit & [sharedMyManager edit]
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settingKey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(-23, 0, 70, 40);
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];
}

- (void)edit
{
    NSLog(@"CLICKED");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In + method you can't use `self` for that puspose, because `self` in class method returns `Class` and not the instance.

replace

`[button addTarget:self action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

with

`[button addTarget:sharedMyManager action:@selector(edit) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Of course , if your sharedMyManager is static field.
And make sure that your sharedMyManager was already initialized before calling that method.

Comment: Place your 
`static PozisyonOzetiTableCell *sharedMyManage;` to outside from this method.